# Updating/installing non-system-critical applications

Tags: software-installation, upgrade

Is rebooting recommended after updating/installing non-system-critical   applications?

Comment: No. You should really only need to reboot after upgrading your kernel. Anything else you can just restart (if you feel it is necessary)...

Comment: The only reason you want to reboot is to ensure that your application will start in case of unexpected reboot.

Answer (score 1):

As jasonwryan already indicated rebooting is not necessary, unless you have upgraded your kernel. And then it is only necessary if you want to run the new kernel immediately, you can also continue to use the (old) kernel, with which you ran the upgrade, until there is a more appropriate moment for rebooting).

If you install [ksplice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ksplice), [kGraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGraft) or [kpatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kpatch) you can even patch the kernel without a need to reboot.